# AppDynamics vs Zipkin as APM Tools

Tags: zipkin, appdynamics, apm, opentracing

What are the differences in features between AppDynamics and Zipkin apart from the pricing since zipkin is opensource. Can any of them show request or response, in their console?

Answer (score 4):

Zipkin only does tracing. APM tools like Appdynamics do other monitoring (browser, mobile, database, server, network). Code-level diagnostics with automated overhead controls and limiters. Don't forget log analytics and transaction analytics. It also collects metrics.

There is a lot more to APM than just tracing, which is what Zipkin does. You could do this with a stack of 20 open source tools, but you'd have to deal with disjointed UIs and data models not to mention the work associated with keeping them all working.